# java.lang.OutofMemory exception occurs with the gallery function

Tags: android

Im trying to create a gallery which will contain a number of pictures.

I have only one activity which will display this, and besides the gallery there will be an enlargement below the current gallery picture. Here is a picture to demonstrate what I'm talking about:

Picture: [1] https://cdn.tutsplus.com/mobile/uploads/legacy/Android-SDK_GalleryView/gallery_complete.png

The problem I have is that the java.lang.OutOfMemory exception occurs when I run the app, even though I'm quite sure that I'm not exceeding the memory heap.

Here is my Java Code:

```
package com.exple.v1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Integer[] pics = {R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.two,

            };
    private ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Gallery gallery = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery1);

        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pic: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                imageView.setImageResource(pics[position]);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        int imageBackground;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context)
        {

            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setImageResource(pics[position]);


            return imageView;
        }

    }


}
```

Here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context="com.exple.v1.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/gallery1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.90" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="El che"
            android:src="@drawable/elche" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my entire errorlog:

```
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358): Process: com.exple.v1, PID: 2358
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:367)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at com.exple.v1.MainActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:82)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.Gallery.makeAndAddView(Gallery.java:865)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.Gallery.fillToGalleryRightLtr(Gallery.java:819)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.Gallery.fillToGalleryRight(Gallery.java:763)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.Gallery.layout(Gallery.java:672)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.Gallery.onLayout(Gallery.java:357)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-09 09:13:49.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2358):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652836/android-out-of-memory-error check this

Comment: Didn't help me, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bitmaps anywhere else in your app you need to make sure that you call .recycle() on it when it is no longer used.  The reason being that even when the java object goes out of scope, the native object is still left in memory.

Alternatively it could be to do with the size of the drawables. (what size are they out of curiosity?)

Comment: there are 3 pictures, first two are 3264 x 2448, and the third one is 202 x 249.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed the sizes of the pictures and I have a gallery now! thank you!